# Can I request a mod to delete an answer?

Tags: support, answers

Just wondering.  I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17323850/996493) earlier today that had 2 incorrect answers on it, which both interestingly had up-votes despite being incorrect.

Then a 4th person answered the question (correctly) in a different way than my answer.  I downvoted both incorrect answers and told them in comments how they were incorrect.  They later in the day proceeded to edit their answers to COPY the other correct answer (answer #4), rather than just deleting...

I feel that they were "cheating" just to try to keep the points they earned.

Is there a way I can request a mod to delete those answers?  Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: Can you Link us to the question? It's hard to tell what intervention ( if any) is needed without specifics.

Comment: Kind of a slippery slope here (going after duplicate answers). I feel like copying answers isn't that common (from what I have seen). In my opinion though it at least warrants some attention.

Comment: I guess this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17323850/1190388 ?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - That's the one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see plagiarism, flag the post, choose "other", and explain what the problem is.  Link to the post that was copied; don't just say "copied another answer", which would make the moderators dig through all the history.

Being wrong is not a reason to delete an answer, but being stolen is.  Because the plagiarism entered via an edit, the logical response would be to revert the edit, not delete the answer (though the author might then decide to delete it, which is fine).  If the answer was plagiarized from the beginning, moderators will usually delete it.

Of course, you need to beware of people independently coming up with the same answer.  If the question is new and several people answer at the same time with the same code correction, that doesn't establish nefarious intent.  It doesn't sound like that's your case, but I'm including it for the sake of completeness, as a moderator who sometimes sees misplaced accusations of copying.